# How do I set inline CSS to a component via Delphi in TMS Web Core?

Tags: css, delphi, inline-styles, tms-web-core

In JavaScript, you can directly change the CSS on an element by simply going into the style object and changing the styles in it such as:

```
MyButton.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
MyButton.style.color = 'red';
```

Is there a way to do this using Delphi code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/blog.asp?post=1078) was super helpful in terms of showing how to work with CSS in TMS Web Core.

You can set inline CSS using Delphi with the following code:

```
MyButton.ElementHandle.style.setProperty('background-color', 'blue');
MyButton.ElementHandle.style.setProperty('color', 'red');
```

Comment: All controls seem to derive from `TWebControl`, which always has a `.ElementHandle` of type `TJSHTMLElement`. [Support > Manuals > WEB components > Developers Guide](https://download.tmssoftware.com/download/manuals/TMSWEBCoreDevGuide.pdf) has a few code examples using this property.