# Get/Set Browser Cookies with Delphi Code in a TMS Web Core Website

Tags: delphi, cookies, tms-web-core

In JavaScript, it is pretty simple to work with Cookies. You get and set cookies via the `document.cookie` code.

Here's example JavaScript code that I've written to get and set Cookies:

```
function getCookie(cookie_name) {
    const name = cookie_name + "=";
    const decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    const ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(let i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        let c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ')
            c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0)
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function setCookie(cookie_name, value, minutes) {
    let expires = "";
    if (minutes) {
        let date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(minutes*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires="+date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = cookie_name + "=" + value + expires + ";SameSite=Strict; path=/";
}
```

How do I get and set cookies using Delphi in TMS Web Core?

Comment: look in WEBLib.Cookies, TCookie, TCookies.  Page 420 of the dev guide.  Not sure if you're posting this to answer yourself or not.

Comment: @JohnEasley Thanks. I'm checking in `WebLib.Cookies` now. I'm working on an answer, but I'm still trying to get the cookies code to work. Can you post a link to the dev guide please? Where can I find this dev guide?

Comment: Isn't this `TWebCookies` on page 452 of [what I already linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77251540#comment136192819_77251541)?

Comment: Thanks @AmigoJack! I didn't click on the link in the other post as I had already figured it out by the time you posted it. I didn't realize it was a whole 704-page book on TMS Web Core. I guess I'll be going through that book this upcoming weekend 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get and set cookies using the `TCookies` class from the `WEBLib.Cookies` unit.

Here are two functions I wrote for getting and setting cookies in pure Delphi code:

```
uses WEBLib.Cookies, System.DateUtils;

...

procedure SetCookie(cookie_name, value: String; minutes: UInt64);
var
  Cookies: TCookies;
begin
  Cookies := TCookies.Create;
  Try
    Cookies.Add(cookie_name,value, IncMinute(Now,minutes));
    Cookies.SetCookies;
  Finally
    Cookies.Free;
  End;
end;

function GetCookie(cookie_name: String): String;
var
  Cookies: TCookies;
  Cookie: TCookie;
begin
  Result := '';
  Cookies := TCookies.Create;
  Try
    Cookies.GetCookies;
    Cookie := Cookies.Find(cookie_name);
    if Assigned(Cookie) then
      Result := Cookie.Value;
  Finally
    Cookies.Free;
  End;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the other answer as that is the Delphi way of doing it, but if you want to get and set cookies without using the `WEBLib.Cookies` unit, then you can use the two functions below:

```
procedure SetCookie(cookie_name, value: String; minutes: UInt64);
begin
  asm
    let expires = '';
    if (minutes) {
      let date = new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime()+(minutes*60*1000));
      expires = "; expires="+date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = cookie_name + "=" + value + expires + ";SameSite=Strict; path=/";
  end;
end;

function GetCookie(cookie_name: String): String;
begin
  Result := '';
  cookie_name := cookie_name + '=';
  asm
    const decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    const ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(let i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
      let c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ')
        c = c.substring(1);
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0)
        Result = c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    Result = "";
  end;
end;
```

The above code is almost the same as the other answer, but this uses a mix of Delphi and JavaScript code. This answer also doesn't require the `WEBLib.Cookies` or `System.DateUtils` unit.